# Azure Point to Site port 445

Tags: azure, port, vpn, point

I've setup Azure point to site and I'm able to connect from my computer to an Azure VM (file share). I'm also able to ping my computer IP address from the Azure VM. However, I'm not able to connect to any resource on my local computer. When trying to access a file share on my computer from the Azure VM I get the following error:

file and print sharing resource (169.254.108.240) is online but isn't responding to connection attempts.

The remote computer isn’t responding to connections on port 445, possibly due to firewall or security policy settings, or because it might be temporarily unavailable. Windows couldn’t find any problems with the firewall on your computer.

Port 445 is enabled on my local computer:

netsh firewall set portopening TCP 445 ENABLE

As an additional test If I issue a \169.254.108.240 from my local computer point to itself it works fine. The same try from the Azure VM gives me the error above.

Thanks,

Comment: Is your computer directly connected to the Internet??? Or is there a firewall between your PC and the internet? Tipically the default config of a router does not allow inbound connection from internet to internl pc.

Comment: Initial test was performed behind a firewall but it doesn't work from home either.

Answer (score 0):

Your IP address (169.254.*) is a non-routable address. You'll need to get a valid IP (say with DHCP, or set manually) and allow connections to your machine. If you have a firewall, this means adding a NAT rule to it.

If possible, try making the connection from another computer on your LAN to isolate any other firewall/Azure issues.

Comment: I have now a more 'routable' address: 172.16.0.2 (Azure VM) and 172.16.0.3 (local computer). From Azure VM I can ping local computer. From local computer I can ping Azure VM and also connect to resources (file share for example). However, I'm still not able to access local computer from Azure VM. Error: file and print sharing resource (172.16.0.3) is online but isn't responding to connection attempts. The remote computer isn’t responding to connections on port 445.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to consider several concepts while implementing azure network, first try to put point to site network on a different range of IPs (like 10.4.0.0) then try to disable firewall on your computer and try again, if you have proper routing device it should go through and get the feedback form the local machine.